# GreenDao how to implement callbacks

Tags: java, android, greendao

I have a trouble, i need to get event/callback when i try to write to database.
I added greenDao lib to project, and i able to write/delete in db.
But no idea how to get callback after some operation under db.

In introduction to lib i read *"AsyncOperationListener for asynchronous callback when operations complete"*. 
Used this tutorial:
http://blog.surecase.eu/using-greendao-with-android-studio-ide/

Can anybody help me with this trouble?

**UPD:**

ok here we added some list in storage

```
getMyObjectDao().getSession().startAsyncSession().insertOrReplaceInTx(MyObject.class, list);
```

error here

```
List<MyObject> items = getBoxDao(c).getSession().startAsyncSession().loadAll(MyObject.class);
```

How can we asynchronously load data from db?

Is this correct solution?

```
            @Override
            public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
                String operationIs = null;

                switch (operation.getType()) {

                    case LoadAll:
                itemsList = BoxRepository.getAllBoxes(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: cannot you use a ContentProvider generated by GreenDao?

Comment: @pskink can u link me some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default all the operations are performed synchronously, eliminating the need to get any callback. But the recent version of `GreenDAO` introduces `AsyncSession`, which can be used to perform operations asynchronously and also provides a way set listener on it. See the example below:

```
    AsyncSession asyncSession = App.getInstance().daoSession.startAsyncSession();
    asyncSession.setListener( new AsyncOperationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
            // do whats needed
        }
    });
    asyncSession.insert(MyObject);
```

Simple ask if anything unclear!

Comment: @Garf1eld Please create  a new question with the new issue, i'll submit the answer to it!

Comment: See here please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121550/greendao-asynchronously-loadall-methood