# GreenDao asynchronously loadAll methood

Tags: java, android, greendao

I can successfully insert rows asynchronously using `GreeDAO`'s `AsyncSession` like this:

```
getMyObjectDao().getSession().startAsyncSession().insertOrReplaceInTx(MyObject.class, list);
```

How can I load all objects from db into ArrayList asynchronously. So far I have tried below code but its not working:

1-

`<List>items = getBoxDao(c).getSession().startAsyncSession().loadAll(MyObject.class)`;

2-

```
        @Override
        public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
            String operationIs = null;

            switch (operation.getType()) {

                case LoadAll:
            itemsList = BoxRepository.getAllBoxes(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab the fetched arrayList with `operation.getResult()` method, like this:

```
AsyncSession asyncSession = App.getInstance().daoSession.startAsyncSession();
    asyncSession.setListener(new AsyncOperationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAsyncOperationCompleted(AsyncOperation operation) {
            itemsList = (List<MyObject>) operation.getResult();
        }
    });
    asyncSession.loadAll(MyObject.class);
```

**UPDATE:**
`BoxRepository` is just a Helper class, its `getAllBoxes()` loadsAll data synchronously but you can easily add another method like this which loads all the data asynchronously:

```
public static void getAllBoxes(Context context, AsyncOperationListener listener) {
    AsyncSession asyncSession = App.getInstance().daoSession.startAsyncSession();
    asyncSession.setListener(listener);
    asyncSession.loadAll(Box.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its works!
But where we must use BoxRepository.getAllBoxes()
and what difference?